# What status should I return if OAuth2 callback is invalid

Tags: http, oauth-2.0

In OAuth2, my server first redirects user to the service's authorization server. If the user accepts and everything goes well, the auth server should redirect the user back to the callback url that I have defined with a proper authorization code.

However, if the request to the callback url is invalid (ie malformed parameters, missing auth code, etc.), what status should the server return? I'm thinking 400 Bad Request or maybe 500 Internal server error, but it really isn't the server's fault.

Answer (score 1):

[RFC 6749 Section 4.1.2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.2.1) describes this situation.

"If the request fails due to a missing, invalid, or mismatching redirection URI, or if the client identifier is missing or invalid, the authorization server SHOULD inform the resource owner of the error and MUST NOT automatically redirect the user-agent to the invalid redirection URI"

There are further description as to the error message to be added.